# Need solution to extract translatable strings from twig templates with if statments

Tags: php, twig, gettext

I have twig template with if statements e.g.

```
{% if condition == true %}
   <div>{% trans 'Translate Me' %}</div>
{%endif%}
```

How to extract this translation to pot file?

What i have tried:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html#extracting-template-strings

https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor

Problem: Template is rendered only once and others conditions are left behind.

Regex solution to find and extract strings from trans functions is not ideal.

I am not using any other framework. gettext is used to translate strings.

Maybe problem is in my template structure? So how to deal with it?

Looking for any tips and tricks to find a decent solution or remarks on flawed implementation.